How raiserror if condition not match
I have user defined table I want to make condition if stock qty >= source.Qty then subtract else raiserror('Qty not enough', 16, 1)
This is my code
MERGE Stock AS TARGET 
USING @InvoiceLines AS SOURCE 
      ON (TARGET.ProductID = SOURCE.ProductID AND TARGET.Qty >= SOURCE.Qty)

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
        SET Qty = TARGET.Qty - SOURCE.Qty;


Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results

@DaleK it subtract even if the stock 0 will be -1 I want to raiserror if the condition not matched

Please edit your question to clarify that.

You could check your table for any rows with quantity less than zero after the merge, and if any existing, rollback the transaction and throw an error

Note, don't use raiserror, use throw

@DaleK can edit my code and show me the correct syntax

@DaleK I don't know the correct syntax to do throw exption  if Qty less, can you make your change to my code

Refer to documentation Use THROW to raise an exception

@Squirrel the problem with my  (merge syntax) when not matched its only allow insert ,update , delete  , I can't make throw exption

@Squirrel i have tried many times can you edit my code syntax to match my needs

MERGE ...... IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Stock WHERE Qty < 0)  THROW ......

Why Merge when a simple Update is sufficient?

It looks like you just need an IF EXISTS. Just checking @@ROWCOUNT is not enough if there is more than one row that needs modifying.
Note also:

Use an explicit transaction and a UPDLOCK or SERIALIZABLE hint to ensure proper locking.
Use SET XACT_ABORT ON to guarantee proper rollbacks.
Use THROW not RAISERROR, as this respects rollbacks better.
The ON of a MERGE should only be the join condition, all other conditions must go in a CTE or in the WHEN MATCHED THEN clause.
Having said that, it looks like you can just use a simple joined UPDATE.

SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRAN;

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM Stock AS s WITH (UPDLOCK)
    JOIN @InvoiceLines AS il
      ON s.ProductID = il.ProductID
    WHERE s.Qty < il.Qty
)
    THROW 50001, N'Qty not Enough', 1;

UPDATE s
SET Qty -= il.Qty
FROM Stock AS s
JOIN @InvoiceLines AS il ON il.ProductID = s.ProductID;

COMMIT;


@yes I checked my old answer when one of products have qty remains still return 1 ROWCOUNT, I did your answer and it's work perfectly thanks alot

I solved by check @@Rowcount if 0 mean no row affected, part of my code
       BEGIN 

       MERGE Stock AS TARGET 
       USING @InvoiceLines AS SOURCE 
       ON (TARGET.ProductID = SOURCE.ProductID AND TARGET.Qty >= SOURCE.Qty )
       WHEN MATCHED THEN
         UPDATE SET Qty =TARGET.Qty - SOURCE.Qty;
         IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
         RAISERROR('Qty not Enough', 16, 2) 
          
       END 


BEGIN CATCH
    declare @error int, @message varchar(4000), @xstate int;
    select @error = ERROR_NUMBER(), @message = ERROR_MESSAGE()
    ,@xstate = XACT_STATE()
    IF @xstate = -1
        rollback;
    IF @xstate = 1 and @trancont = 0
        rollback
    IF @xstate = 1 and @trancont > 0
        rollback transaction mytran
    --IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    --BEGIN
        RAISERROR(@message, 16, 1)  
    --  ROLLBACK
    --END
END CATCH



Use THROW not RAISERROR, and why throw just to catch, you can conditionally rollback without a catch

Also if there is more than one row to be modified then this won't work at all.
